# Spring validate related request parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
@ResponseBody
public Object test(@RequestParam("latitude") String latitude, 
                   @RequestParam("longitude") String longitude) {
}
```

In this case if latitude is not null than longitude must be not null.

How to validate related request parameters?
Is there out-of-the-box solution, or to validate manually?

Comment: You shouldn't use a String to represent a latitude or a longitude. Use the appropriate data type: a double or a BigDecimal. A double can't possibly be null, and Spring will validate that. You can annotate arguments with Bean validation annotations (`@NotNull` here). Check the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using recent version of the spring then there is a annotation `@Validated`.

With this annotation we can validate both `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable`

The most important thing to notice is that `@Valid` which is used to validate the `RequestBody` throws the exception **`MethodArgumentNotValidException`**

While the `@Validated` throws **`ConstraintViolationException`**

Because both of the exceptions are of different types you have to handle them differently using `@ExceptionHandler`, something like below:-

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { ConstraintViolationException.class })
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ResponseEntity<Type> handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
    // your code here to handle the exceptions accordingly 
}

@ExceptionHandler(value = { MethodArgumentNotValidException.class })
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ResponseEntity<Type> handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {
    // your code here to handle the exceptions accordingly 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:

1. Bind in a DTO both Longitude and Latitude and let Spring do the type parameter binding without separate `@RequestParam`s
2. Create a custom exception, below the `LongLatException`, and bind it directly to the **HTTP Error code** of your liking (below `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST`)
3. Do your tailored check (either both present or absent) directly on the endpoint and accordingly throw the exception.

Fully working 1 file code:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MyController {


    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String test(LongLat longLat) {
        if(isNotValid(longLat)) {
            throw new LongLatException();
        }
        return "latitude: "+longLat.getLatitude() + ", longtitude: " + longLat.getLongitude();
    }

    private boolean isNotValid(LongLat longLat) {
        return (longLat.getLongitude() == null && longLat.getLatitude() != null) ||
                (longLat.getLongitude() == null  && longLat.getLatitude() == null);
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    static class LongLatException extends RuntimeException {

        public LongLatException() {
            super("Longitude and Latitude params either need to be both present or empty");
        }
    }

    static class LongLat {

        private final String latitude;
        private final String longitude;

        public LongLat(String latitude, String longitude) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

        public String getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        public String getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String sb = "LongLat{" + "latitude='" + latitude + '\'' +
                    ", longitude='" + longitude + '\'' +
                    '}';
            return sb;
        }
    }
}
```